# Character Changes After Insertion into Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding, character-encoding

I am running a query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO [Table]([Col1],[Col2],[Col3]) VALUES ('A','B','Ａｃcount');
```

But after the insertion, the Ａｃcount becomes Account.

I'd like to maintain original Ａｃcount letters, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you share the table schema in SQL? Need to know that Col3 is nvarchar type, not just varchar

Answer (score 0):

What is the filed type of Col3? Also, try:

```
INSERT INTO [Table]([Col1],[Col2],[Col3]) VALUES ('A','B',N'Ａｃcount');
```

The N in front of the value indicates that it's Unicode.